# How to subtract a number of weeks from a yearweek/weeknumber in R?

Tags: r, date, lubridate, week-number

I have a couples of weeknumbers of interest. Lets take '202124' (this week) as an example. How can I subtract x weeks from this week number?
Lets say I want to know the week number of 2 weeks prior, ideally I would like to do `202124 - 2` which would give me `202122`. This is fine for most of the year however `202101 - 2` will give `202099` which is obviously not a valid week number. This would happen on a large scale so a more elegant solution is required. How could I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert the year week values to dates subtract in days and format the output.

```
x <- c('202124', '202101')
format(as.Date(paste0(x, 1), '%Y%W%u') - 14, '%Y%V')
#[1] "202122" "202052"
```

To convert year week value to date we also need day of the week, I have used it as 1st day of the week.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work most of the time, but this 2020 had a 202053 week, which this doesn't seem to catch.

Comment: @JasperNabSq I think we should use `%V` in `format` which starts week number from 1. `%W` starts from 0. See the updated answer.